# Aligning content in independent divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can you please tell me how to make the content of the second `div` aligned to the bottom? That the two boxes would be the same size without setting the `height`?

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
1<br>
2
</div>
<div>
1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this you need a parent container with `display: flex` to stretch their Childs and the add `align-items: flex-end;` to child `div`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1<br> 2
  </div>
  <div>
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They are independent divs and do not have a common parent.

Comment: @vector i think the only way to do it is to put them into a parent, if you want to put the divs independently you need to set height and align them manually

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end
}
.container div {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>
1<br>
2
</div>
<div>
1
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: They are independent divs and do not have a common parent.

Comment: I think you can add parent element to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vertical-align: bottom` to align those divs bottom. But as far as my knowledge you can't get same height without adding a parent element or set height property

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* Bottom Align */
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
1<br>
2
</div>
<div>
1
</div>
```